# Displaying a To-Many Relationship in a Table View

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I've got an application I've been working on.  There are projects and employees, projects can have several employees, employees can work on several projects.

Right now I want selecting a project to display which employees are related to it, and allows me to add employees I select from another full-roster list.  Somehow, this has proven more complicated, because (at least for now), selecting different projects still displays the same list of employees, as if all employees who'd been assigned to any project, belong to all of them.

What part of Master-Detail am I missing?

Comment: How are your array controllers defined, bound, and displayed?

Comment: Both the employee and project array controllers are set to their entities, and ManagedObjectContext bound to the File's Owner, a view controller with a MOC.  The sub-array is where I imagine the problem would be.  I feel like I've tried every combination, hence asking for the right one, generally with the same result.  For example, I've tried binding the project "selection.members" to the main project AC.  I've also tried binding to the File's Owner's MOC, and KVCing the selection...members through the table view's value.  So far, no combination gives unique teams to the projects.

Comment: I just made another version to unit-test this feature...  The error is the same:  The "Projects" Entity is not KVC-compliant for mutableArrayForKey: teamMembers.  Isn't this the sort of thing Core-Data is supposed to do for us?  Do I just need to subclass my Projects entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:  The relationship Array Controller needed to be bound by its "Content Set" not by its "Content Array".